# How to create apple-app-site-association file for Universal Linking in IOS 9?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, ios-universal-app

I have some problem in creating apple-app-site-association file.I don't know how to create json file without json extentsion and have content type `application/json` for the same file.I want to use this file  without any signing as it doesn't need in IOS 9 but I couldn't able to create the valid apple-app-site-association file.

I have setup everything on my app like associated domains,app delegate method,provisioning profiles.

Here is my code on the backend side:

```
{
    "applinks": {
      "apps": [],
      "details": [
          {
             "appID": "teamID.bundleID",
             "paths": [ "*" ]
          }
      ]
   }
 }
```

Comment: did you manage to make it work?

Comment: @Abilash Bansal, did u finished this creation of json file, if so, how u did that, now im facing same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Another method is to use file match to match exactly your file and to enforce the required content-type:

add following lines to your `.htaccess` file:

```
<FilesMatch "^apple-app-site-association$">
    ForceType application/json
</FilesMatch>
```

this worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

Open your terminal and type

> cd desktop

press return key and then type

> touch apple-app-site-association

press return

a file is created without any extension

Answer (score 4):

I added the following to the .htaccess file in the root folder. This is a bit rough, but it worked for me to return the file in application/json

```
RewriteRule ^apple-app-site-association$ - [env=apple:1]
Header set Content-type application/json env=apple
```

I was not able to make Universal Link work with iOS9 serving application/json yet. Let me know if you made i work.